# Is it possible using the Microsoft Role provider to "temporarily" add a user to a role at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

I am implementing a custom Membership Provider and a custom Role Provider.  It is working fine.  I have a custom database that has all of my users and all of the roles and *most* of the associations between users and roles.  There are a few roles where the code to figure out who is in the role is much more complicated.  It sort of needs to be done on a user by user basis and there is no simple way to return a list of all of the users in one of these other roles.  So what I am trying to do is add the user to the role at runtime.  So when the user logs in I will get most of their roles from the custom Role Provider.  However I want to run some additional code at login to check and see if they are also part of these other two roles.  If they are then I want to add those two roles to the user sort of "temporarily" - for the session.  In other words I want my application to know that they are part of those roles, but I don't want the provider to attempt to persist that back to the underlying database.  I hope I have described this correctly.

Am I even thinking about this correctly?  Is this the right approach?  Can this be done?

Please let me know if this is unclear or doesn't make sense.

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make it fit when it won't.  Don't bother with the role provider; just do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you started coding before you completed and verified the design. I'd honestly advise you to start again and properly define your roles.